# Generate WSDL file from WSDL URL

Tags: java, soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

I have a WebService definition exposed on http://localhost:8080/myService?wsdl

This WSDL contains many external schema imports.

I want to save this WSDL to file (single one or wsdl + xsd - whatever).

I know that `SoapUI` can do that via `Export definition`, however I'm working on Windows and `SoapUI` throws:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
d:\myService_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_13_14_15_16_17_18_19_20_21_22_23_24_25_26_27_28_29_30_31_32_33_34_35_36_37_38_39_40_41_42_43_44_45_46_47_48_49_50_51_52_53_54_55_56_57_58_59_60_61_62_63_64_65_66_67_68_69_70_71_72_73_74_75_76_77_78_79_80_81_82_83.xsd 
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

As you can see i have like 83+ .xsd file which cousing too long filename (on Windows).

Any idea how to change a SoapUI naming convention or how to export definition to file with other tool?

Comment: Why not use a shorter file name?

Comment: @kjhughes i'm afraid u didnt use SoapUI never. It is autogenerated name. Every next xsd from wsdl is named with _X and if it is 83th xsd i will be named like above.

Comment: You caught me:  i didnt use SoapUI never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click and choose "Show Interface Viewer". Choose the tab "WSDL Content". Right-click the WSDL in the right-hand side and choose "Select All", then "Copy". Paste into Notepad and Save.

(2016/04/13 Update incorporating my own comment below) Alternately:

Try [Merging WSDL and XSD files](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/rebuildall/2011/06/20/Merging_WSDL_and_XSD_files) which has the description of a free tool to do this. It has a link to [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdlmerge/) for the source code and binary. On the Google Code page, click the [Downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdlmerge/downloads) link on the left to download only the Windows binary, if you prefer not to build it from source code.

Comment: When I open WSDL Content, on the right-hand side I have 1 wsdl and multiple xsd opened in tabs. WSDL have imports still so when i copy it, this gives me nothing.

Comment: Try [Merging WSDL and XSD files](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/rebuildall/2011/06/20/Merging_WSDL_and_XSD_files) which has the description of a free tool to do this. It has a link to [Google Code page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdlmerge/) for the source code and binary. On the Google Code page, click the [Downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/wsdlmerge/downloads) link on the left to download only the Windows binary, if you prefer not to build it from source code.

Comment: Exacly what I need :)

Comment: I was waiting for your edit (adding this comment to answer) but I will do it for you then :)